# How to get system time of another system in same network?

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I know how to get current system date and time using datetime in python. Is there any way to get date and time of another system in the same network using python language ? I googled it a lot but didn't find anything useful. Basically, I'm using beaglebone black (using usb ethernet connection with host) to implement traffic management system. Using datetime, program returns time of beaglebone. Instead i want host system's time. how can i do that ?

Comment: Your program could telnet or ssh in to the other computer and run 'date', and parse the output.  Or if you are able to run custom software on the remote system, you could run a server there that responds to a TCP connection or UDP ping by sending back the current time as a response.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, make sure that the client machine has been authorized to log into the destination machine without inputting a password,
python code:

```
import os

remote_date = os.popen("ssh user@yourhost date").readline()
print remote_date
```

output:
`Thu Jan  1 13:33:48 CST 2015`

maybe helpful to you:)